# Get CUPS to align page properly?

Tags: cups

Print outs are losing a line of text off the top of the page and adding blank lines at the bottom.

Is this a problem with CUPS or a problem with my Kyocera printer driver?

*UPDATE: it's probably a mechanical failure. see comment below from @Freddy (and his [link](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=de&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fforum.ubuntuusers.de%2Ftopic%2Fkyocera-fs-1030dn-beginn-der-seite-fehlt-auf-d%2F%23post-8936058)). It's an old printer.*

CUPS test page lops a bit off the top, and adds almost 1cm of white space at the bottom margin.

From Gedit, about 1 line is lost off the top, and about 6.5 lines (almost 3cm) off the bottom. Similar with LibreOffice. Left and right-hand margins are okay.

CUPS test page says: Media Limits: 0.17 x 0.14 to 8.10 x 11.56

The printer is a Kyocera FS-1030D. It is using a4 paper.

[Printer properties / Printer options dialog] says: Media Size: A4

Here's the debug output to /var/log/cups/error_log:

```
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15654] Accepted from localhost (Domain)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15654] Waiting for request.
I [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] Expiring subscriptions...
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 360] Unloading...
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] Report: clients=6
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] Report: jobs=360
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] Report: jobs-active=0
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] Report: printers=2
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] Report: stringpool-string-count=54670
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] Report: stringpool-alloc-bytes=15216
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] Report: stringpool-total-bytes=997160
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15654] POST / HTTP/1.1
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Not busy"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15654] Read: status=200
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15654] No authentication data provided.
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15654] 2.0 CUPS-Get-Default 1
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] CUPS-Get-Default
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15654] Returning IPP successful-ok for CUPS-Get-Default (no URI) from localhost
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15654] Content-Length: 1150
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15654] cupsdSendHeader: code=200, type="application/ipp", auth_type=0
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15654] con->http=0x56245b05d880
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15654] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_STATE_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODING_LENGTH, data_remaining=1150, response=0x56245b1c9be0(IPP_STATE_DATA), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15654] Writing IPP response, ipp_state=IPP_STATE_DATA, old wused=0, new wused=0
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15654] bytes=0, http_state=0, data_remaining=1150
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15654] Flushing write buffer.
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15654] New state is HTTP_STATE_WAITING
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15654] Waiting for request.
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Active clients"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15654] HTTP_STATE_WAITING Closing for error 32 (Broken pipe)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15654] Closing connection.
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Not busy"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15655] Accepted from localhost (Domain)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15655] Waiting for request.
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15655] POST /printers/FS-1030D HTTP/1.1
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Not busy"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15655] Read: status=200
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15655] No authentication data provided.
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15655] 2.0 Create-Job 2
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] Create-Job ipp://localhost:631/printers/FS-1030D
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdMarkDirty(---J-)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients and dirty files", busy="Active clients"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] add_job: requesting-user-name="user1"
I [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Adding start banner page "none".
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdMarkDirty(----S)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients and dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
I [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Queued on "FS-1030D" by "user1".
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15655] Returning IPP successful-ok for Create-Job (ipp://localhost:631/printers/FS-1030D) from localhost
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15655] Content-Length: 201
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15655] cupsdSendHeader: code=200, type="application/ipp", auth_type=0
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15655] con->http=0x56245b05d880
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15655] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_STATE_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODING_LENGTH, data_remaining=201, response=0x56245b1f6000(IPP_STATE_IDLE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15655] Writing IPP response, ipp_state=IPP_STATE_DATA, old wused=0, new wused=0
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15655] bytes=0, http_state=0, data_remaining=201
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15655] Flushing write buffer.
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15655] New state is HTTP_STATE_WAITING
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15655] Waiting for request.
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Notifier] state=3
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Notifier] JobCreated
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15655] HTTP_STATE_WAITING Closing for error 32 (Broken pipe)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15655] Closing connection.
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Dirty files", busy="Dirty files"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15656] Accepted from localhost (Domain)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15656] Waiting for request.
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15656] POST /printers/FS-1030D HTTP/1.1
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients and dirty files", busy="Dirty files"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15656] Read: status=200
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15656] No authentication data provided.
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15656] 2.0 Send-Document 3
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] Send-Document ipp://localhost:631/printers/FS-1030D
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdIsAuthorized: requesting-user-name="user1"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Auto-typing file...
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Request file type is text/plain.
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdMarkDirty(---J-)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients and dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
I [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] File of type text/plain queued by "user1".
I [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Adding end banner page "none".
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdMarkDirty(---J-)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients and dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] time-at-processing=1550019962
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdMarkDirty(---J-)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients and dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients and dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdMarkDirty(----S)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients and dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] 4 filters for job:
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] texttopdf (text/plain to application/pdf, cost 32)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] pdftopdf (application/pdf to application/vnd.cups-pdf, cost 66)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] pdftops (application/vnd.cups-pdf to application/vnd.cups-postscript, cost 100)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] - (application/vnd.cups-postscript to printer/FS-1030D, cost 0)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] job-sheets=none,none
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] argv[0]="FS-1030D"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] argv[1]="361"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] argv[2]="user1"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] argv[3]="print test"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] argv[4]="1"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] argv[5]="finishings=3 number-up=1 job-uuid=urn:uuid:6df6caef-50d0-3b08-714a-1cd0fd20ea0d job-originating-host-name=localhost date-time-at-creation= date-time-at-processing= time-at-creation=1550019962 time-at-processing=1550019962 document-name-supplied=print\\ test"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] argv[6]="/var/spool/cups/d00361-001"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[0]="CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[1]="CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[2]="CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/cups/doc-root"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[3]="CUPS_FONTPATH=/usr/share/cups/fonts"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[4]="CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/spool/cups"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[5]="CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[6]="CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[7]="CUPS_STATEDIR=/var/run/cups"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[8]="HOME=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[9]="PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[10]="SERVER_ADMIN=root@system1"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[11]="SOFTWARE=CUPS/2.1.3"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[12]="TMPDIR=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[13]="USER=root"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[14]="CUPS_MAX_MESSAGE=2047"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[15]="CUPS_SERVER=/var/run/cups/cups.sock"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[16]="CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[17]="IPP_PORT=631"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[18]="CHARSET=utf-8"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[19]="LANG=en_GB.UTF-8"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[20]="PPD=/etc/cups/ppd/FS-1030D.ppd"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[21]="RIP_MAX_CACHE=128m"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[22]="CONTENT_TYPE=text/plain"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[23]="DEVICE_URI=usb://Kyocera/FS-1030D?serial=XMF6Y09297"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[24]="PRINTER_INFO=Kyocera FS-1030D"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[25]="PRINTER_LOCATION=system1"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[26]="PRINTER=FS-1030D"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[27]="PRINTER_STATE_REASONS=none"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[28]="CUPS_FILETYPE=document"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[29]="FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-postscript"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] envp[30]="AUTH_I****"
I [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/texttopdf (PID 12012)
I [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf (PID 12013)
I [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftops (PID 12014)
I [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Started backend /usr/lib/cups/backend/usb (PID 12015)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdMarkDirty(----S)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients, printing jobs, and dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15656] Returning IPP successful-ok for Send-Document (ipp://localhost:631/printers/FS-1030D) from localhost
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15656] Content-Length: 171
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15656] cupsdSendHeader: code=200, type="application/ipp", auth_type=0
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15656] con->http=0x56245b05d880
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15656] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_STATE_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODING_LENGTH, data_remaining=171, response=0x56245b1fbe20(IPP_STATE_DATA), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15656] Writing IPP response, ipp_state=IPP_STATE_DATA, old wused=0, new wused=0
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15656] bytes=0, http_state=0, data_remaining=171
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15656] Flushing write buffer.
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15656] New state is HTTP_STATE_WAITING
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15656] Waiting for request.
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Active clients, printing jobs, and dirty files"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Notifier] state=3
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Notifier] PrinterStateChanged
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Notifier] state=3
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Notifier] JobState
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15656] HTTP_STATE_WAITING Closing for error 32 (Broken pipe)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15656] Closing connection.
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Page = 595x842; 12,10 to 583,832
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Loading USB quirks from \"/usr/share/cups/usb\".
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Loaded 131 quirks.
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Printing on printer with URI: usb://Kyocera/FS-1030D?serial=XMF6Y09297
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] pdftops - copying to temp print file \"/tmp/02eee5c6bb69b\"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] libusb_get_device_list=9
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] STATE: +connecting-to-device
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdMarkDirty(---J-)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdMarkDirty(----S)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Dirty files", busy="Dirty files"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Notifier] state=3
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Notifier] PrinterStateChanged
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] STATE: -connecting-to-device
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdMarkDirty(---J-)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Dirty files"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdMarkDirty(----S)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Notifier] state=3
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Notifier] PrinterStateChanged
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Device protocol: 2
I [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Sending data to printer.
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdMarkDirty(---J-)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Set job-printer-state-message to "Sending data to printer.", current level=INFO
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdMarkDirty(----S)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdMarkDirty(----S)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Notifier] state=3
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Notifier] JobProgress
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Notifier] state=3
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Notifier] PrinterStateChanged
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] PID 12012 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/texttopdf) exited with no errors.
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] PID 12013 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf) exited with no errors.
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Printer make and model: Kyocera FS-1030D
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Running command line for pstops: pstops 361 user1 \'print test\' 1 \'finishings=3 job-uuid=urn:uuid:6df6caef-50d0-3b08-714a-1cd0fd20ea0d job-originating-host-name=localhost date-time-at-creation= date-time-at-processing= time-at-creation=1550019962 time-at-processing=1550019962 document-name-supplied=print\\ test\'
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Using image rendering resolution 600 dpi
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Deactivated compression of pages in Ghostscript\'s PostScript output (\"psdebug\" debug mode or Kyocera/Utax printer)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Running command line for gs: gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=ps2write -sOUTPUTFILE=%stdout -dLanguageLevel=3 -r600 -dCompressPages=false -dCompressFonts=false -dNoT3CCITT -dNOINTERPOLATE -c \'save pop\' -f /tmp/02eee5c6bb69b
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Started filter gs (PID 12021)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Started post-processing (PID 12022)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Started filter pstops (PID 12023)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Inserted workaround PostScript code for Kyocera and Utax printers
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Page = 595x842; 12,10 to 583,832
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] slow_collate=0, slow_duplex=0, slow_order=0
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Before copy_comments - %!PS-Adobe-3.0
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] %!PS-Adobe-3.0
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] %%BoundingBox: 0 0 595 842
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] %%HiResBoundingBox: 0 0 595.00 842.00
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] %%Creator: GPL Ghostscript 926 (ps2write)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] %%LanguageLevel: 2
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] %%CreationDate: D:20190213010602Z00\'00\'
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] %%Pages: 2
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] %%EndComments
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Before copy_prolog - %%BeginProlog
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Read 4096 bytes of print data...
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] PID 12021 (gs) exited with no errors.
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Wrote 4096 bytes of print data...
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Read 8192 bytes of print data...
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Wrote 8192 bytes of print data...
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Read 8192 bytes of print data...
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Wrote 8192 bytes of print data...
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Read 8192 bytes of print data...
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Wrote 8192 bytes of print data...
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Read 8192 bytes of print data...
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Wrote 8192 bytes of print data...
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Read 8192 bytes of print data...
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] PID 12022 (Post-processing) exited with no errors.
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Wrote 8192 bytes of print data...
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Read 8192 bytes of print data...
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Wrote 8192 bytes of print data...
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Read 8192 bytes of print data...
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Wrote 8192 bytes of print data...
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Read 8192 bytes of print data...
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Wrote 8192 bytes of print data...
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Job 361] Read 8192 bytes of print data...
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15657] Accepted from localhost (Domain)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15657] Waiting for request.
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15658] Accepted from localhost (Domain)
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15658] Waiting for request.
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15657] POST / HTTP/1.1
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients, printing jobs, and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15657] Read: status=200
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15657] No authentication data provided.
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15657] 2.0 Get-Notifications 172
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] Get-Notifications /
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] cupsdIsAuthorized: requesting-user-name="user1"
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15657] Returning IPP successful-ok for Get-Notifications (/) from localhost
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15657] Content-Length: 1765
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15657] cupsdSendHeader: code=200, type="application/ipp", auth_type=0
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15657] con->http=0x56245b05d880
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15657] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_STATE_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODING_LENGTH, data_remaining=1765, response=0x56245b18ddb0(IPP_STATE_DATA), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15657] Writing IPP response, ipp_state=IPP_STATE_DATA, old wused=0, new wused=0
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15657] bytes=0, http_state=0, data_remaining=1765
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15657] Flushing write buffer.
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15657] New state is HTTP_STATE_WAITING
D [13/Feb/2019:01:06:02 +0000] [Client 15657] Waiting for request.
```

I have .ppd files for this printer, in different locations:

```
/usr/share/cups/model/Kyocera/Kyocera_FS-1030_en.ppd
/etc/cups/ppd/FS-1030D.ppd
```

both have a header, thus:

```
*FileVersion: "8.2"
*FormatVersion: "4.3"
*LanguageEncoding: ISOLatin1
*LanguageVersion: English
*Product: "(FS-1030D)"
*PSVersion: "(3011.103) 1"
*Manufacturer: "Kyocera"
*ModelName: "Kyocera FS-1030D"
*ShortNickName: "Kyocera FS-1030D"
*NickName: "Kyocera FS-1030D"
*PCFileName: "KC1030EN.PPD"
```

An excerpt of their page references:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/cups/ppd/FS-1030D.ppd | grep page

*Resolution 300dpi/300 dpi: "<< /HWResolution [300 300] /PreRenderingEnhance false >> setpagedevice"
*Resolution 600dpi/600 dpi: "<< /HWResolution [600 600] /PreRenderingEnhance false >> setpagedevice"
*Resolution 1200dpi/Fast 1200: "<< /HWResolution [600 600] /PreRenderingEnhance true >> setpagedevice"

*PagePolicy On/AutoSizeSelect: "<< /DeferredMediaSelection true >> setpagedevice"
*PageSize A4/A4: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [595 842] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageSize A5/A5: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [420 595] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageSize A6/A6: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [297 420] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageSize B5/B5 (JIS): "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [516 729] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageSize ISOB5/B5 (ISO): "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [499 709] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageSize B6/B6: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [363 516] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageSize OficioII/Oficio II: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [612 936] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageSize Folio/Folio (210 x 330mm): "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [595 935] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageSize Statement/Statement: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [396 612] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageSize P16K/16K: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [558 774] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageSize Letter/Letter: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [612 792] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageSize Legal/Legal: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [612 1008] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageSize Executive/Executive: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [522 756] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageSize EnvPersonal/Envelope #6: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [261 468] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageSize Env9/Envelope #9: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [279 639] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageSize Env10/Envelope #10: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [297 684] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageSize EnvMonarch/Envelope Monarch: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [279 540] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageSize EnvDL/Envelope DL: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [312 624] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageSize EnvC5/Envelope C5: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [459 649] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
  currentpagedevice /PageSize get aload pop
*PageRegion A4/A4: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [595 842] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageRegion A5/A5: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [420 595] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageRegion A6/A6: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [297 420] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageRegion B5/B5 (JIS): "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [516 729] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageRegion ISOB5/B5 (ISO): "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [499 709] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageRegion B6/B6: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [363 516] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageRegion Letter/Letter: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [612 792] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageRegion Legal/Legal: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [612 1008] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageRegion Executive/Executive: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [522 756] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageRegion EnvPersonal/Envelope #6: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [261 468] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageRegion Env9/Envelope #9: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [279 639] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageRegion Env10/Envelope #10: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [297 684] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageRegion EnvMonarch/Envelope Monarch: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [279 540] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageRegion EnvDL/Envelope DL: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [312 624] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageRegion EnvC5/Envelope C5: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [459 649] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageRegion OficioII/Oficio II: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [612 936] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageRegion Folio/Folio (210 x 330mm): "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [595 935] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageRegion Statement/Statement: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [396 612] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
*PageRegion P16K/16K: "<< /Policies << /PageSize 7 >> /PageSize [558 774] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice"
  >> setpagedevice"
*InputSlot Internal/Cassette 1: "<< /ManualFeed false >> setpagedevice statusdict begin 0 setpapertray end"
*InputSlot PF17/Cassette 2: "<< /ManualFeed false >> setpagedevice statusdict begin 1 setpapertray end"
*InputSlot MF1/Multi Purpose Feeder: "currentpagedevice /InputAttributes get 3 get null eq
{ <</ManualFeed true>> setpagedevice }{ statusdict begin 3 setpapertray end } ifelse"
*MediaType PrnDef/Printer Default: "<</ManualFeed false /DeferredMediaSelection true >> setpagedevice"
*MediaType Plain/Plain Paper: "<</ManualFeed false /MediaType (Plain) /DeferredMediaSelection true >> setpagedevice"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a problem with your hardware. Check your printer test page or a test print on Windows. A "scotch tape" fix/solution is linked on the (german) ubuntu forum (last comment) [Kyocera FS-1030DN: Start of page is missing on the paper](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=de&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fforum.ubuntuusers.de%2Ftopic%2Fkyocera-fs-1030dn-beginn-der-seite-fehlt-auf-d%2F%23post-8936058).

Comment: This very much looks like the answer. You are right, the printer's own test page is also out. A dreaded linux printing/CUPS prejuduce angled my question. The solution you point to looks marvellous. I will try it. Thank you.